# Related select in Magento how I do

Tags: magento, jquery, select

It's possibile, in Magento, create two or more related select?
For example Country / Region
I try with jQuery but seem doesn't work.
Best Regards

I try with this code: in Mymodule output

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/mymodule/mymodule.phtml

```
   <div id="continenti">
<?php
include_once 'option.class.php';
$obj = new Option();
$obj->ShowContinenti();
?>
</div>

<div id="nazioni">
Seleziona una nazione:<br>
<select id="sel_nazioni" name="sel_nazioni"><option value="no">Scegli...</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

In my app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/head.phtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#sel_continenti').change(function(){

            var cont = $('#sel_continenti').attr('value');

            $.post("selection.php", {id_cont:cont}, function(data){
            $("#sel_nazioni").empty();
            $("div#result").empty();
            $("#sel_nazioni").prepend(data);
            });
            });

$('#sel_nazioni').change(function(){

            var id_naz = $('#sel_nazioni').attr('value');

            $.post("result.php", {id:id_naz}, function(data){
            $("div#result").empty();
            $("div#result").prepend(data);
            });
            });

});
</script>
```

In my app/code/local/frontname/mymodule/sql/mysql4-install-0.1.0

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("

    -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('continenti')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('continenti')} 
          `id` INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `continente` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

        INSERT INTO `continenti` (`id`, `continente`) VALUES
        (1, 'Europa'),
        (2, 'Africa'),
        (3, 'Sud America');

        -- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('nazioni')};
    CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('nazioni')} 
          `id` INT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `id_cont` INT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
          `nazione` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

        INSERT INTO {$this->getTable('nazioni')} (`id`, `id_cont`, `nazione`) VALUES
        (1, 1, 'Spagna'),
        (2, 1, 'Francia'),
        (3, 1, 'Italia'),
        (4, 1, 'Germania'),
        (5, 1, 'Belgio'),
        (6, 2, 'Egitto'),
        (7, 2, 'Marocco'),
        (8, 2, 'Tunisia'),
        (9, 2, 'Uganda'),
        (10, 3, 'Argentina'),
        (11, 3, 'Cile'),
        (13, 3, 'Brasile');

    ")

    ;




     $installer->endSetup();
```

File result.php

```
<?php
include_once 'option.class.php';
$obj = new Option();
$obj->ShowResult();
?>
```

File selection.php

```
<?php
include_once 'option.class.php';
$obj = new Option();
$obj->ShowNazioni();
?>
```

The first select appear with the content of Region Table but, if I click and choise one region, the second select doesn't load data inside itself.

EDIT: resolved!
I change my head.phtml in

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('#sel_continenti').change(function(){

            var cont = jQuery('#sel_continenti').attr('value');

            jQuery.post("selection.php", {id_cont:cont}, function(data){
            jQuery("#sel_nazioni").empty();
            jQuery("div#result").empty();
            jQuery("#sel_nazioni").prepend(data);
            });
            });

jQuery('#sel_nazioni').change(function(){

            var id_naz = jQuery('#sel_nazioni').attr('value');

            jQuery.post("result.php", {id:id_naz}, function(data){
            jQuery("div#result").empty();
            jQuery("div#result").prepend(data);
            });
            });

});
</script>
```

I change $ with jQuery word!

Comment: Put some code. What you already tried?

Comment: I have post the code! Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Magento already has this kind of selects in checkout addresses phtmls, just that it uses Prototype.

```
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
        <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select region, state or province') ?></option>
    </select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
    //]]>
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
</div>
```

```
<div class="field">
<label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
<div class="input-box">
    <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
</div>
```

```
var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
If I would like another type of select for example Brand and Version in my own output Module, How I do?

Comment: Depending on how much javascript you know, you can use my example and look inside `js/varien/form.js` to see the class RegionUpdater and make a function update in your own js file like the method from it. You can either echo a json (in a phtml file) with your select options and update with values from it or make an ajax call to retrive those values, Magento uses the echoed json.

Comment: Thank you Emi, I posted my code, I think that can be helpfull!

Comment: Woah, sorry to say that is some ugly code (not Magento way), I'll post a response later when I have time to code something.

Comment: Thank you! I'll waiting for :)